# How to select all identically faces on object

Tags: selection-tools

[image]

Hello, how can I select all faces that are identicall as those I already selected. Those are strawberry seeds, and I want to select them all at once. Is there some useful tool to help me with that? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that you are in Face mode, select the face and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> > *Area* (or header menu > *Select > Select Similar > Area*).

[image]

You can tweak the threshold in the *Operator* box:

[image]